# Strings mixed up reading from internal storage

Tags: android, string, android-studio, buffer, read-write

I'm using internal storage to store multiple strings entered by the user through multiples edit text.

So the layout is composed of multiples Textviews which correspond to the title of the fields, and multiples Edittexts which correspond to the fields where the user can enter his string.

When the user has finished, he presses the save button and this function is triggered :

```
public void  save(View view)  // SAVE
    {
        File file= null;
        String name = editname.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String marque = editmarque.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String longueur = editlongueur.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String largeur = editlargeur.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String tirant = edittirant.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String immatri = editImmatriculation.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String port = editPort.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String contact = editContact.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String panne = editPanne.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String poste = editPoste.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String police = editPolice.getText().toString()+"\n";
        String assurance = editAssurance.getText().toString();

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {

            file = getFilesDir();
            fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("Code.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //MODE PRIVATE
            fileOutputStream.write(name.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(marque.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(longueur.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(largeur.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(tirant.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(immatri.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(port.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(contact.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(panne.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(poste.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(police.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(assurance.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved \n" + "Path --" + file + "\tCode.txt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editname.setText("");
            editmarque.setText("");
            editlargeur.setText("");
            editlongueur.setText("");
            edittirant.setText("");
            editImmatriculation.setText("");
            editPort.setText("");
            editContact.setText("");
            editPanne.setText("");
            editPoste.setText("");
            editPolice.setText("");
            editAssurance.setText("");
            return;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Than, in another file I retrieve this data through another button that triggers this function :

```
public void  load(View view)
    {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream =  openFileInput("Code.txt");
            int read = -1;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while((read =fileInputStream.read())!= -1){
                buffer.append((char)read);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            String tab[] = buffer.toString().split("\n");
            String boatname = tab[0];
            String marque = tab[1];
            String longueur = tab[2];
            String largeur = tab[3];
            String tirant = tab[4];
            String immatri = tab[5];
            String port = tab[6];
            String contact = tab[7];
            String panne = tab[8];
            String poste = tab[9];
            String assurance = tab[10];
            String police = tab[11];
            getboatname.setText(boatname);
            getmarque.setText(marque);
            getlongueur.setText(longueur);
            getlargeur.setText(largeur);
            getTirantdeau.setText(tirant);
            getImmatriculation.setText(immatri);
            getPort.setText(port);
            getContact.setText(contact);
            getPanne.setText(panne);
            getPoste.setText(poste);
            getAssurance.setText(assurance);
            getPolice.setText(police);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So in the *save function* I'm splitting the entered strings with \n, and I save the file to the internal storage, and in the *load function* I retrieve the strings using an array and splitting with every \n and I set the text with the correct index.

What I don't understand is that the results are all mixed up, the string of the first field is displayed in the last field for example, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Make a Single String and write it. Also, use a different separator. You can use StringBuffer for it.

```
StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();
s.append(editname.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editmarque.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editlongueur.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editlargeur.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(edittirant.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editPort.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editContact.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editPanne.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editPoste.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editPolice.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");
s.append(editAssurance.getText().toString());
s.append("##@@##@@##");

 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {

            file = getFilesDir();
            fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("Code.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //MODE PRIVATE
            fileOutputStream.write(s.toString().getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved \n" + "Path --" + file + "\tCode.txt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editname.setText("");
            editmarque.setText("");
            editlargeur.setText("");
            editlongueur.setText("");
            edittirant.setText("");
            editImmatriculation.setText("");
            editPort.setText("");
            editContact.setText("");
            editPanne.setText("");
            editPoste.setText("");
            editPolice.setText("");
            editAssurance.setText("");
            return;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

When you get FileInputStream split the String with this "##@@##@@##" vlaue